# Type Mismatch in passing Cells(3,4) as a Range argument

Tags: excel, vba, range, cells, type-mismatch

I'm writing a small class in Excel VBA with a sub that takes Range as an argument. But when I try to call it using Cells I get type mismatch error. (Calling using Range works fine)

Code excerpt:

```
Dim Com, Gua As Worksheet
Set Com = Worksheets(cCom)
Set Gua = Worksheets(cGua)

Dim myFirm As clsFirm
Set myFirm = New clsFirm
Call myFirm.Init(Gua.Cells(3, 4))  '<--ERROR HERE
Call myFirm.Init(Gua.Range("E3"))  ' this line works
```

And here is the sub:

```
Public Sub Init(nameCell As Range)
    pAddress = nameCell.Address
    pName = nameCell.Value2
    pContract = nameCell.Offset(0, -3).Value2
    pAmount = nameCell.Offset(0, 2).Value2
    pRate = nameCell.Offset(0, 1).Value2
    pStartDate = CDate(nameCell.Offset(0, -2).Value2)
    pEndDate = CDate(nameCell.Offset(0, -1).Value2)
End Sub
```

Comment: Does `Gua.Range(Cells(3, 4))` works? I'm not sure how a `ByVal` argument may affect your procedure, but give a try to see, sometimes it's pretty helpful!

Comment: Maybe this would work `Call myFirm.Init(Gua.Cells(3, 4).Range)`

Comment: hmm, i'd like to know the answer to this. from my understanding, they should both return a range.

Comment: What content is in the cell "D3" which causes the error? I suppose that ```Call myFirm.Init(Gua.Cells(3, 5))``` works, right?

Comment: I agree with @dee. The tests in your sample code are using two different cells (`Gua.Cells(3, 4)` is not E3) and both work fine if tested on an empty sheet. I suspect you have an issue with the values in your cells. Have you stepped through the code using breakpoints and F8 to double-check which line causes the error.